# Configure subgit for a single directory inside the SVN

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I am trying to set up `subgit` for a huge SVN repository. This repository is very old, so to tidy up the structure a little, I want to make seperate git-repositories for various subdirectories.

Suppose the SVN is at `/svn` and has the subdirectories `project1`, `project2`, etc.

This works

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url file:///svn/ git.git
$ subgit install git.git
```

This also works, but creates an empty repository

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url file:///svn/project1/ /tmp/project1.git
$ subgit install /tmp/project1.git
[...]
Translating Subversion revisions to Git commits...

    Subversion revisions translated: 6563.
    Total time: 1 seconds.

INSTALLATION SUCCESSFUL
[...]
$ git clone /tmp/project1.git
Cloning into 'project1'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
```

In the SVN there are actually files inside `project1`. Why doesn't it work with subgit and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that after running `subgit configure` and before running `subgit install` you have to adjust config file at `$GIT_REPO/subgit/config`. By default SubGit generates the following options there:

```
[svn]
  url = file:///svn/project1
  trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
  branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
  tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
  shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
```

I suppose your Subversion repository has some non-standard layout; in this case you have to specify branches and tags options correctly, so SubGit can detect and convert them properly.

It would help me if you could list children of *file:///svn/project1* directory and describe how branches and tags were created and merged in this repository.

E.g. if there is only one single branch for the whole project and this branch is *file:///svn/project1*, then you can use the following options:

```
[svn]
  url = file:///svn/
  trunk = project1:refs/heads/master
  branches = branches/project1/*:refs/heads/*
  tags = tags/project1/*:refs/tags/*
  shelves = shelves/project1/*:refs/shelves/*
```

Please find more information on configuration and installation stages in [SubGit Book](http://subgit.com/book-remote/#installation-stages).

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with SVN (that's why I want to convert it to git) so I have get into more detail regarding the branching stuff. But my first try worked so far thanks to your help.

Comment: My case is similar and I was nervous about giving tags and branches paths that do not exist, but it seems to have worked just fine and it has not (yet) created a branches or tags directory.  Thanks!

Comment: @vadishev what do I do if the svn repo does not have any branches or tags or anything and everything was just committed to "master" ?